# Automatically generate Date + 4-digit sequence number for ID in Access 2010+

Tags: date, ms-access, ms-access-2010, primary-key, auto-generate

I need to automatically generate a 12 character value for my Business Key. Without any user interaction.

```
8 character -> Today Date        (yyyymmdd or ddmmyyyy).
+
4 character -> Sequential Number (0001,0002,0003).
```

The Sequential Number must reset on each new day.

Is it possible to do this in Microsoft Access 2010+ without any coding involved?

Comment: You would have to store that sequential number somewhere and the current today's date.  Are you looking to store it in a table and then run sql queries to generate the 10 character values as well as update the stored last value in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Access 2010+ the best way to accomplish your goal would be to use a Before Change data macro like this

[image: DataMacro.png]

To create the Before Change macro, click the "Before Change" button on the "Table" tab of the ribbon when the table is open in Datasheet View:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

For more details on Data Macros see

[Create a data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Good question, thanks for the challenge!

After some search, it seems it's possible to do that.

You can prefix the AutoNuber value by processing like the explanation available here: http://www.databasedev.co.uk/add_prefix.html

You can try to specify in the format of the field a `format(now(),"ddmmyyyy")`.

Check this page for more informations, another user seems to have the same problem and got a solution: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/695188-custom-made-autonumber-show-todays-date

Hope it's helping you!

Comment: I downvoted this answer. See  [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/275530) for an explanation why.