# Access New ID Field YYYYMMNN

Tags: ms-access

So I'm trying to create a new field in my table that will automatically populate. So its a new ID row that not running off `autonumber`. I want it to look like `20160201` so that year month and numbers based on how many records have been put in that month.

After reading the answer from [Automatically generate Date + 4-digit sequence number for ID in Access 2010+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312900/automatically-generate-date-4-digit-sequence-number-for-id-in-access-2010) I'm still having issues. The New ID Field isnt populating in the table.

Comment: Please show us your work so far!

Comment: I cant because its on a offline system. Im just trying to create a new field for ids. Also i haven't tried anything because I don't know how to auto generate a field.

Comment: Right now the field is set to number. I think i should add 3 numbers just in case so YYYYMM999 should be the most. I think it should still count even if a record was deleted. 2010