# Sequential Number Column with YYYYMM

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

What I'm trying to do is have a new column that isn't an autonumber. I'm trying to create a new column that easy to search for a record later on. So if today was the first record for the month it would look like 20160201.

I have read [Automatically generate Date + 4-digit sequence number for ID in Access 2010+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312900/automatically-generate-date-4-digit-sequence-number-for-id-in-access-2010) but its not generating the number in the field.

Other info:

- Table name `tbl_TIPS`
- Also this is on an offline system
- Column name `TIPSid`

Comment: What do you mean "its not generating the number in the field"? Despite the variable in data macro you referred is string, but it will be automatically converted to number when the value will be assigned to database field. All you need - just slightly correct format of generated number and rename table/field in select

Comment: After adding the Data Macro (changed the field names in the macro). When creating a record it doesn't populate the number