# Access 2010+ before update macro

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-data-macro

Can anyone else replicate this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312900/automatically-generate-date-4-digit-sequence-number-for-id-in-access-2010)?

I get an error saying the code does not validate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20661510/2144390)? I was opening the table in Design View and then trying to modify the macro and it wouldn't work that way. However, once I started opening the table in Datasheet View and then modifying the macro it worked fine.

Comment: Hi Gord, many thanks for the reply.
I think I finally got the code to validate but the field within the table remains blank when I add a new record. Please refer to below screen captures I am about to attach. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any option to  upload screen captures. I'm wondering if the blank field problem is to do with how the field data type is declared, should this be Number or Text?

Comment: The field should be `Text(12)`.

Comment: I set the field to Text with 12 characters but still get a blank field when adding records. Also tried resetting the table with the Repair Tool but still the same result. I have added some links to screen captures above in my original post.

Comment: Your final `SetField` action is inside the `Look up a record in` block. Move it down to have it outside that block (but still within the `If [IsInsert]` block).

Comment: Your a genius. Thanks very much.